# Search by index in indexeddb

Tags: jquery, indexeddb

I'm using this plugin: https://github.com/axemclion/jquery-indexeddb/tree/gh-pages
I want to use indexes but I can't understand how the get Method works on indexes. My idea is to search by given index, e.g. $.indexedDB("OfflineDB").objectStore("users").index("userName").get("My user name")
So I want to find the data for user with name "My user name" directly, I don't want to iterate over all stored objects because it would be too slowly.
Any ideas how I could make this work?

Answer (score 1):

```
var index = store.index("name");
var request = index.get("frstname");
request.onsuccess = function () {
    var matching = request.result;
    if (matching !== undefined) {
        // A match was found.
        report(matching.isbn, matching.title, matching.author);
    } else {
        // No match was found.
        report(null);
    }
};
```

Answer (score 0):

Using the get method on an index does not iterate over all stored objects in an object store. Looking at the [source code](https://github.com/axemclion/jquery-indexeddb/blob/gh-pages/src/jquery.indexeddb.js) of this wrapper, the get method just wraps the normal IDBIndex.get method. According to the [MDB documentation](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/IDBIndex.get), "[t]he IDBIndex.get method ... finds ... the value in the referenced object store that corresponds to the given key ..."  According to the [indexedDB spec](http://www.w3.org/TR/IndexedDB/#index), IDBIndex.get follows [the normal steps for retrieving a value by key](http://www.w3.org/TR/IndexedDB/#dfn-steps-for-retrieving-a-referenced-value-from-an-index).  This essentially involves the following step: "If key is not a key range then find the first record with key key from index. If key is a key range, then find the first record from index whose key is in key."

Retrieving an object by key does not involve explicit iteration. It is similar to using a hashmap to obtain a value for a key. It is similar to looking up the value in an array by specifying its index.

For example, it is basically doing this:

```js
var data = {"My user name": user1, "other username": user2, 
      "another username": user3};

function lookupValueForKey(username, index) {
  return index[username];
}

var user = lookupValueforKey("My user name", data);
```

It is **not** doing this:

```
function lookupValueForKey(username, index) {
  for(var key in index) {
    if(key == username) {
       return index[key];
    }
  }
}
```

Because that would defeat the entire purpose of using an index. That does not even make sense.